# GO | opentelemetry | setting xray client name

Tags: go, amazon-cloudwatch, open-telemetry

Sending traces from Go / EKS based microservices via opentelemetry to ADOT collector. Im getting the traces fine but all the services are named "client" in the xray service map and I don't see how to configure this value.

Comment: Are you sending the "service.name" resource attribute?

Comment: Yes. In the `sdktrace.WithResource(res)` call. Res is `resource.Merge` with semconv.ServiceName() set to the service name.

Comment: setting this `service.name` attribute in resource should work